# How to install Libertas Firmware

Tags: firmware, libertas

I have a case where trying to install the `libertas-firmware` package results in:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libertas-firmware : Depends: firmware-libertas but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Of course, I actually do not have any held or broken packages and the dependency package `firmware-libertas` does not exist on the repositories which makes me think that the `libertas-firmware` is actually a dummy meta package for the `firmware-libertas` package. But how can I install the libertas drivers then if the dependent package is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bit of a screw up in the packaging. In this case, [`firmware-libertas` is available from Debian](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze-backports/firmware-libertas).

If you download that, install it with `dpkg -i whateverthefilenameis.deb` you should be able to install `libertas-firmware` (which *is* just a metapackage that depends on `firmware-libertas`) and then whatever depends on that.

Oh and [report a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libertas-firmware/+filebug) so the developers know there's a problem.

Comment: This has to be the first ever for me to see this case.

Comment: It gives an error:  trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/mwl8k/helper_8366.fw', which is also in package linux-firmware 1.106
 but at least I know where the problem lies.

Comment: Yeah it seems (`dpkg -L linux-firmware | grep libertas`) that `linux-firmware` is providing a lot of the firmware available in the `firmware-libertas` package, but not all of it.